# find number of positive integers smaller $N$ that have an even number of proper divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisor-counting-function

Given a number $N$, I want to determine $\vert\{x\in\mathbb{N}\ \vert\ 1\leq x\leq N\wedge\ \text{candidate}(x)\}\vert$

where

$\text{candidate}(x) = \vert\{y\in\mathbb{N}\ \vert\ 1\leq y < x \wedge x \mod y = 0\}\vert\ \mod 2 = 0$

Really stuck with this and would appreciate some help.

Comment: So you look for numbers that have an odd number of divisors including themselves. Do you know a formula for the number of divisors of $n$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The candidates are precisely the perfect squares (because all divisors $d\ne\sqrt x$ come in pairs $d,\frac xd$, where special care is needed for $1$ and $x$). Hence the desired number is $\lfloor\sqrt N\rfloor$.